# \numberwithin makes the first equation unnumbered

Tags: equations, numbering, amsmath

I might be doing something stupid, but the following code produces a document with the first equation unnumbered (only an empty set of parentheses is given). The second equation is correctly numbered as 1.1.2. If I remove the change to `\theequation`, then everything is counted normally.

```
\documentclass[draft,fleqn,openany]{book}
\usepackage[tbtags]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{xkeyval}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainfont[BoldFont={* Bold},ItalicFont={* Italic},BoldItalicFont={* Bold Italic},SlantedFont={Linux Libertine Slanted O}]{Linux Libertine O}
\usepackage[letterpaper]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\numberwithin{equation}{section}}
\allowdisplaybreaks[1]
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=british]{english}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\title{A test document}
\author{AstroPig7}
\date{}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapter{One}
Test document.
\section{Two}
Test document.
\begin{equation}
\text{Test.}
\end{equation}
\subsection{Three}
\begin{equation}
\text{Test.}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

I’ve also tried removing various non-essential declarations from the preamble with no success.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my moment of illiteracy. That did it. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)'s `\numberwithin{<slave>}{<master>}` does a couple of things. It:

1. checks whether the counters `<slave>` and `<master>` exist. If they do, then it
2. redefines the presentation of the `<slave>` counter to include the master using the format `<master>.<slave>`; and
3. adds `<slave>` to the reset list of `<master>`. That is, `<slave>` will reset to 0 whenever `<master>` is incremented.

Here it is, in super high definition, from [`amsmath.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/amsmath.sty):

```
\newcommand{\numberwithin}[3][\arabic]{%
  \@ifundefined{c@#2}{\@nocounterr{#2}}{%
    \@ifundefined{c@#3}{\@nocnterr{#3}}{%
      \@addtoreset{#2}{#3}%
      \@xp\xdef\csname the#2\endcsname{%
        \@xp\@nx\csname the#3\endcsname .\@nx#1{#2}}}}%
}
```

So, you would *only* need

```
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
```

to achieve what you're after.